# How to save a array object into Chromes local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, local-storage, vuex

I am building a Budget-Calculator-App which should save the user data into chromes local storage.
Idea is that everyone can use this app from his device whiteout a need of a database.

I am stuck on saving my whole data state into the local storage. I did a screenshot to show what i mean and what i get instead of the array of objects.
[image: preview of what my output is]

As you can see i am not getting the array saved and i don't know why.

---

Here is the code:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    users: [
      {
        userName: 'John',
        salary: 2000,
        leftover: 0,
        active: false,
        inc: [],
        exp: []
      }
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    users: state => {
      return state.users;
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    addNewUser: (state, payload) => {
      state.users.push(payload);
    }
  },
  actions: {
    saveStateInStorage: (context, payload) => {
      context.commit('addNewUser', payload);
      // save current state into chrome local storage
      console.log(context.state.users);
      let userData = context.state.users;
      localStorage.setItem('budgetCalcUserData', userData);
    },
    updateStorageState: context => {
      console.log(context);
    }
  },
  modules: {}
});
```

All works fine except the saving into the local storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the *stringified* array:

Try

```
localStorage.setItem('budgetCalcUserData', JSON.stringify(userData));
```

When access you have to parse that:

```
var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('budgetCalcUserData'));
```